# Dockerfile got error while install dependen cairocffi

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm installing petereport (https://github.com/1modm/petereport) with Dockerfile. But there is a problem when running.
When installing, step 12 standing for very long time (~2 hours) without any action.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                       
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1155, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
ERROR: Service 'petereport' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get install -y   python3.8   python3-pip   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've tried to execute the command and it ran normally in another tab terminal.
[image]

Here is my OS:[image]

I added `-y` and it got another error.

```
Step 34/34 : RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
 ---> Running in 1c49886075d9
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
 self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 174, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 222, in get_legacy_dependencies
    result = reqset._prepare_file(self.finder, ireq, ignore_requires_python=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 644, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 134, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/req/req_install.py", line 435, in run_egg_info
    call_subprocess(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/utils/__init__.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(
pip9.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp3g_r4makbuild/cairocffi/

The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'petereport' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text - this should be pasted into the question directly. 
But, I believe you're simply missing the `-y` from the `add-apt-repository` command

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still cannot run.